# Python Scrape: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am running into this error and have read the articles here but am still having a hard time understanding where and how it should be applied.

```
import csv
import requests
import os

req = requests.get('https://data.nba.com/data/10s/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2017/league/00_full_schedule_week.json')
data = req.json()

my_data =[]
sched = data['lscd']['mscd']
for item in sched['g']:
    game_id = item['gid']
    my_data.append([game_id])
headers = ["game_id"]

with open("NBA_sched.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Please pst the full traceback.

Comment: full stacktrace please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `data['lscd']` is a `list`, not a `dict`;

```
In [6]: type(data['lscd'])
Out[6]: list
```

On the other hand, each element of `data['lscd']` is a `dict`, one of whose keys is `'mscd'`, so `data['lscd'][0]['mscd']` would give you the value for the first element in the list (after which you run into the same problem with `item['gid']`, since `item` is a `list`).

Comment: By adding the [0] between them i was able to pull the first "month". I would like to get all of them at once.

Comment: Thanks, I am just going to change the 0 to 1-7 and edit that way. since i only need it once